# Надо сделать программу на С#. Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: c#

Разработать программу ввода названий областей, их площади (кв.км) и количества населения (тыс.чел), расчёта плотности населения в каждой области, добавления этих сведений в поле многострочного редактора и выявления области с максимальной плотностью населения среди перечисленных.

Comment: Отвечающие на этом сайте ставят минусы и закрывают вопросы, если они напоминают ТЗ. Пожалуйста, дополните вопрос [**собственными попытками**](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) справиться с заданием. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Вот набросок для консоли. К формам прикрутите сами. Это не сложное задание. Ну и да, прикладывайте свой код к вопросам.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Help1
{
public class Region
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Название области
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Площадь
    /// </summary>
    public double Square { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Население
    /// </summary>
    public int Population { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Метод для расчета плотности населения
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Плотность населения</returns>
    public double GetPopulationDensity()
    {
        return this.Square / this.Population;
    }

    public Region(string name, double square, int population)
    {
        Name = name;
        Square = square;
        Population = population;
    }

    public Region()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// метод выводит данные в удобном виде
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Название: {0}\t Площадь: {1:N2}\t Кол-во населения: {2}\t Плотность населения: {3:N2}", Name, Square, Population, this.GetPopulationDensity());
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Region> list = new List<Region>()
        {
            new Region("Область 1", 100d, 588),
            new Region("Область 2", 200d, 288),
            new Region("Область 3", 300d, 338),
        };

        //выывод списка областей
        foreach (var region in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(region.ToString());
        }

        //выводим плотность первой
        Console.WriteLine("Плотность первой");
        Console.WriteLine(list[0].GetPopulationDensity().ToString());

        //Ввести данные
        Region newRegion = new Region();
        newRegion.Name = "Область 4";
        newRegion.Square = 123d;
        newRegion.Population = 222;
        list.Add(newRegion);

        //Максимум
        Console.WriteLine("Максимальная плотность");
        var max = list.Max(x => x.GetPopulationDensity());
        Console.WriteLine(max.ToString("N2"));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: *"Чем больше людей купивших диплом -- тем ценнее я как специалист"(С)*